# Lost appearance ubuntu 22.04 lts original

Tags: gnome, 22.04, settings

Lost appearance UBUNTU 22.04 LTS application menu original, when I download gnome-shell-extensions
I need some guidance to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

- Open a terminal
- Enter `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`

The GNOME desktop should be restored to the default.

[reference](https://linuxconfig.org/reset-gnome-desktop-settings-to-factory-default-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, tried a lot of options, but nothing can get it back. I found kind of solution to this. You can install Tweaks `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` or install gnome dock or other [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/#). I installed both and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, but i still have 2 issues :

1. the colors have disappeared (user should be colored while root should not : both look like root now)
2. when i change directory with

> cd

, pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> to show what are my choices will list sub-directories **and** files (not **only** sub-directories ! why ?!)

any idea where to look for getting back to normal behaviour ? (i have re-installed over a 17.04 version, keeping my old settings in the home directory)

Note that i'm running Gnome Terminal Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42
and Unity instead of native Gnome

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1244283)