# Blockscreen lost in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments, login-screen, lock-screen

I'm having problems with the behaviour of ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I don't know why, the block button stoped working. I mean the "lock" icon key in the Logitech MX Keys. I think it stoped working after the lattest update of the nvidia drivers. Moreover, now the Ctrl+Alt+(f1 to f6) changed the behaviour too. The default screen of Ubuntu is lost (the all gray with the credentials in the center). Now I see the black screen with the ugly terminal in the upper left corner `Ubuntu 22.04.02 cesarkero-pc tty1` etc.

If I press Ctrl+Alt+f7 I go back to normal desktop.

If I block the user pushing here, the user is blocked and you go to a gnome style different from default. With a purpled screen, with the login at the left size and with the icon that allows you to select between different desktop styles.
[image]

The main problem with this screen is that, even if I have my pc configured to never put into suspension, if the user is blocked, the pc is suspended anyway. The default blocking screen in Ubuntu didn't behave that way. I was as easy as pushing the lock button in the keyboard and go.

I have reinstall everything (nvidia drivers included) and every starting by default config of desktop [like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413294/lost-appearance-ubuntu-22-04-lts-original).

I hope this all makes any sense and somebody can give me a hint.